# JPA embeddable class constraints not used in embedding class table

Tags: java, jpa, constraints, embeddable

I have an issue with the DDL generated from an embeddable class. The annotations on the properties of the embeddable are not carried over to the embedding class table, such as NOT NULL.

```java
@Entity
public class Contact {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "contact_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Length(max = 63)
    private String fullName;

    @Length(max = 63)
    private String displayName;

    @Length(max = 63)
    private String emailAddress;

    @Embedded
    @NotNull
    private Meta meta;
}

@Embeddable
public class Meta {

    @NotNull
    private Instant created;

    @NotNull
    private Instant lastModified;

    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 1, max = 63)
    private String digest;
}
```

The generated DDL is like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.contact (
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    full_name character varying(63) NOT NULL,
    display_name character varying(63),
    email_address character varying(63),
    created timestamp(6) with time zone,
    last_modified timestamp(6) with time zone,
    digest character varying(63),
);
```

How can I annotate my @Embeddable class so that the @NotNull constraints are preserved in the embedding class?

Comment: Use `@Column(nullable=false)`. I don't know which `@NotNull` you are using (maybe Java Validation API?), but they are not part of JPA AFAIK.

Comment: That is an interesting observation that I never considered. But the fact remains that `Contact.fullName` is marked as `NOT NULL` but `Meta.created` is not.

Comment: Ok, the question is where does the `@NotNull` annotation come from. I have found a Hibernate annotation `NotNull` https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-notnull-vs-nullable which would explain the `NOT NULL` constraint in the DDL. So maybe a wrong import in the `Meta` class?

Comment: It's imported from `jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull`. Now I find this curious. I tried searching for which validation annotations are being honored by JPA, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: Found it: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/?v=8.0#validator-defineconstraints-spec

Comment: JPA doesn't know or care about your NotNull constraints. What you are seeing on full_name is because hibernate is your JPA provider and your validator, and decided to apply the NotNull validation to the JPA column. IMO it should not have, as the default JPA states should be that the column is Nullable, but they can do what they want- and in this case, decided not to pass down that extra column information to the main table for embeddable. file a bug with them, but also note the JPA compliant way to get not null on the column is through the column annotation.

Comment: Chris - you would be right, but the documentation states that it does respect some validation annotations and it does work when applied to the `@Entity` class, so it is in fact probably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

As it was rightly pointed out, I'm using two systems in combination, Jakarta Persistence API (JPA) and Jakarta Validator, both backed in my case by Hibernate implementations.

`@NotNull` is part of the Jakarta Validation API. According to the Jakarta Validator [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/8.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-defineconstraints-spec), it is taken into account by JPA to apply `NOT NULL` to it's respective table column. It seems that this doesn't work with `@Embedded` classes using validation annotations. However, the JPA-native `@Column(nullable = false)` does work.

So the `Meta` class generates the expected DDL like so:

```java
@Embeddable
public class Meta {

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Instant created;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Instant lastModified;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 63)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String digest;
}
```

Credit goes to @kidney for suggesting the solution!